# Custom Agent roles for Mesos Agents in Cloudformation of DCOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I'm stuck in experimenting the Default Cloud formation script of DCOS on AWS. I couldn't figure out a way, where the agent types are being defined or a way to define custom roles for the mesos agents

Answer (score 1):

DC/OS has two high level roles which are Mesos Private Agents and Mesos Public Agents. The only difference between these top level roles are external access (slave_public) and internal access (unreserved role = *). You can still configure these agents by using Mesos Attributes to run a specific set of workload on predefined tagged agents.

More information can be found here:

- http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/attributes-resources/
- https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.10/installing/faq/#q.-how-to-add-mesos-attributes-to-nodes-to-use-marathon-constraints
- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/constraints.html

Comment: The basic CloudFormation templates provided by DC/OS do not allow modifying Mesos agent attributes or resource roles, but you may be able to modify them by generating advanced templates and then modifying them.

Comment: `MESOS_ATTRIBUTES` can be set in `/var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common`, which may exist before dc/os is installed, but if you set `MESOS_RESOURCES` the same way it will overwrite the auto-detected resource definition generated by DC/OS. So either you need to hard code the node resources & roles or you have to write some tooling to set them based on the initial config generated by DC/OS. For example, here's a script that modifies the memory config in `MESOS_RESOURCES`: https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant/blob/master/provision/bin/install-mesos-memory.sh

Comment: I made some changes in the cloud formation script for running the Mesos agents with given 'MESOS_ATTRIBUTES' but not sure where to give 'default_mesos_role'(which is * by default for the slave)

Comment: By adding the MESOS_ATTRIBUTES alone is sufficient. You will not need to many any changes to the mesos role.